# How to integrate upselling into an apps navigation?

Tags: conversion

The company im working with develops an application where customers pay for at least 2 modules (mandatory). We offer four other modules as well, which increase the cost per user and month. Those modules of course offer the customer a lot.

The modules cant be purchased without talking to a person from our company, since we offer individual prices.

Right now:
Users only see the modules they are paying for in the navigation of our app.

CEO asks for:
Display all the modules (up to 6 in total) in the website navigation, even if the user cant access them. After clicking one of those in the navigation the user should be directed to a "whats so good about this module, why you need it, contact us" page.

This seems like bad UX to me, it might get frustrating and navigating throughout the app will be not as easy.

Im thinking about adding a button to our vertical navigation which is labeled "upgrade" for example and when the user clicks it, he gets presented with a modal that presents him the modules he still does not pay for and tells him whats cool about them and offers a "contact us" as a conversion button.

Any other ideas? Arguments against the solution the CEO wants would be appreciated too.
Are there any best practices?

Comment: Why not have a summary list (of checkboxes) showing the courses they have selected, and below, the related/recommended extra courses? Many websites do this already, I think some streaming services do this when a user changes their subscription level (although they use a Radio button instead)